# playing video in Xcode after version 4.2.1

Tags: xcode

It seems like after Xcode version 4.2.1 my video  code won't work?

objective C code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:
  [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"h" ofType:@"mp4"]];

MPMoviePlayerViewController *playercontroller = 
  [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playercontroller];

playercontroller.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;

[playercontroller.moviePlayer play];
// [playercontroller release];
playercontroller = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of

```
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playercontroller];

[[self navigationController]presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playercontroller];
```

If you are using navigation controller.